# Send large number of files to back end Django

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, python-2.7

I have a requirement that i need to upload large number of files using

```
<input type="file" ng-file-model="files" id="id_docfile" multiple>
```

and after that it should be sent to the `django` backend side more efficently.I am also using angularjs for the front end.I am familiar with 2 options

1.Using django forms

2.Send files to backend using angular ajax request(`$http`)

Can i implement any kind of threading mechanism for this?
Can anyone suggest a best option for this?Please keep in mind that a case of even 1000 files upload.

Comment: Are you asking about threading mechanism on server-side or on client-side?

Comment: is there any client side threading mechanism?

Comment: You can send more than one ajax post request simultaneously.

Comment: The question is "are you asking about the way to send multiple files simultaneously in javascript or you asking about the way to receive multiple files simultaneously in django"

Comment: I'm not going to give an answer but I use it like <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

Comment: Either way my real question is how i efficently send large number of files from the frontend to backend using javascript or django @YevgeniyShchemelev

Comment: There is no efficient way in the django. Each file upload connection require one python thread and can receive only one file simultaneously.

Comment: If we talking about gigabytes of data, usually I have problems on channel bandwidth before any problems with django. Django is efficient enough for 1000 files uploaded by one user, but if you have 500 users uploading 1000 files each, you'll have to scale your application and  make a lot of infrastructure changes.